# Eglot spams the minibuffer in Java mode

Tags: minibuffer, java, eglot

I am essentially having [this](https://github.com/joaotavora/eglot/issues/236) issue but for the `java-mode`. Eglot shows too many messages in the java files.

[image]

How can I fix this? I only wanna see the documentation and error messages in the minibuffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, eglot will report when it finished a task need long time(like compilation).

You can suppress this behavior by:

```
(setq eglot-report-progress nil)
```

Press `C-h v eglot-report-progress` to check the doc of this variable.

```
eglot-report-progress is a variable defined in ‘eglot.el’.

Its value is nil
Original value was t

If non-nil, show progress of long running LSP server work

  This variable was introduced, or its default value was changed, in
  version 29.1 of Emacs.
  You can customize this variable.
```

Comment: Love your username lol.

Comment: Thanks, that's just for fun :)

Comment: Also worked for me, thanks! (in a Python project using python-lsp-server)